# How to pass a value in a text file to Azure Devops variable and use in another task

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have the following Powershel script that reads a text file. The value that is read is a value I want to pass as a variable to another step in the Azure Devops yml file

```
$data = Get-Content .\cluster_txt.txt
Write-Output $data
```

How can I access the value in $data in another task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You suppose to use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell) to create Azure Pipelines variable

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=testvar;]$data"
```

and then in next task you can reffer to variable as

```
$(testvar)
```

or

```
$env:TESTVAR
```

Be aware that Azure Pipelines variable will not be available in the task you will create it. And if you need variable in another job or stage then you need [output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable). [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage) you will find how to use it.